# Android ClassCastException in GridLayout

Tags: android

i try to add gridview to gridlayout in android but it shows classcastexception what is the problem and how to solve the exception

```
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout$LayoutParams
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.widget.GridLayout.getLayoutParams1(GridLayout.java:729)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.widget.GridLayout.validateLayoutParams(GridLayout.java:663)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.widget.GridLayout.getLayoutParams(GridLayout.java:734)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.widget.GridLayout.measureChildrenWithMargins(GridLayout.java:866)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.widget.GridLayout.onMeasure(GridLayout.java:894)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-22 22:47:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle);

    // Disable all animations
    getWindow().setWindowAnimations(0);

    // Get grid size/difficulty, default 4x4
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    GRID_SIZE = prefs.getInt("gridSize", 4);

    // get image ID/path from intent
    Integer imageID = getIntent().getIntExtra("image", 0);

    try {
        this.imageGrid = createGrid();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    gridlay = (GridLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);
    gridlay.addView(this.imageGrid);


}
```

private GridView createGrid() throws IOException {
        Bitmap puzzleImage = null;

```
    puzzleImage = loadScaledImage();
    int imageWidth = puzzleImage.getWidth();
    int imageHeight = puzzleImage.getHeight();

    GridView grid = new GridView(this);
    grid.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageHeight));

    grid.setNumColumns(this.GRID_SIZE);
    grid.setColumnWidth(imageWidth/this.GRID_SIZE);

    grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, this.GRID_SIZE, puzzleImage));
    puzzleImage.recycle();

    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ImageAdapter adapter = (ImageAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
            int[] tileOrder = adapter.getTileOrder();
            int blankTile = adapter.BLANK_TILE_ID;

            if (attemptMove(tileOrder, position, blankTile)) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            checkPuzzleSolved(tileOrder);
        }
    });

    return grid;
}
```

Comment: The stacktrace and code don't seem to be related. The stacktrace is from a `GridLayout` in `RelativeLayout`, the code has `GridView` in `LinearLayout`.

Comment: sorry i posted wrong code now i edited

Comment: Grid inside a grid doesn't seem such a good idea... Also, when you're touching layout params, the type must match the parent layout and here it doesn't - hence the class cast exception. It's better to not create layout params in code at all.